# Transfer artifact via SFTP using Maven

Tags: maven, tomcat, ant, sftp

I'm attempting to add a build task into a Maven pom file so that I can transfer a jar file as well as some xml files to an SFTP server (it's a VM with Tomcat installed) but I have been unable to so far.

I've had a look at a few links, but they either don't quite match the requirements, have missing steps, or don't work. I'm basically a beginner with Maven so I'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly.

The requirement is that I want to invoke a Maven build, with command line arguments for the hostname, username, and password (which I have working) which then will upload a jar file and the xml files to a VM with Tomcat running in it via SFTP (FTP doesn't work, and I don't think SCP will work as I don't have a passfile). I also don't want to mess with the main Maven settings.xml file to add the connection details in, which some of the links I found seem to be reliant upon.

I have the following profile so far, using FTP, but it doesn't work due to not using SFTP.

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <!-- maven antrun:run -Pdeploy -->
        <id>deploy</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <inherited>false</inherited>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.6</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <target>
                            <!-- <loadproperties srcFile="deploy.properties" /> -->

                            <ftp action="send" server="${server-url}"
                                remotedir="/usr/share/myappserver/webapps/myapp/WEB-INF/lib"
                                userid="${user-id}" password="${user-password}" depends="no"
                                verbose="yes" binary="yes">
                                <fileset dir="target">
                                    <include name="artifact.jar" />
                                </fileset>
                            </ftp>

                            <ftp action="send" server="${server-url}"
                                remotedir="/var/lib/myappserver/myapp/spring"
                                userid="${user-id}" password="${user-password}" depends="no"
                                verbose="yes" binary="yes">
                                <fileset dir="src/main/resource/spring">
                                    <include name="*.xml" />
                                </fileset>
                            </ftp>

                            <!-- calls deploy script -->
                            <!-- <sshexec host="host" trust="yes" username="usr" password="pw" 
                                command="sh /my/script.sh" /> -->

                            <!-- SSH -->
                            <taskdef name="sshexec" classname="org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.ssh.SSHExec" 
                                classpathref="maven.plugin.classpath" />
                            <taskdef name="ftp"
                                classname="org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.net.FTP"
                                classpathref="maven.plugin.classpath" />
                        </target>

                    </configuration>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>commons-net</groupId>
                            <artifactId>commons-net</artifactId>
                            <version>1.4.1</version>
                        </dependency>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>ant</groupId>
                            <artifactId>ant-commons-net</artifactId>
                            <version>1.6.5</version>
                        </dependency>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>ant</groupId>
                            <artifactId>ant-jsch</artifactId>
                            <version>1.6.5</version>
                        </dependency>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>jsch</groupId>
                            <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
                            <version>0.1.29</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

I tried swapping ftp for sftp, and using org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.ssh.SFTP instead, but it didn't seem to work.

So to summarize, the SFTP config needs to be self contained within the pom file as much as possible, with stuff like the host url, username and password being passed in when invoked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was eventually able to get this working using PuTTy pcsp

```
<PUTTY_DIRECTORY>/pscp.exe" -l <USERNAME> -pw <PASSWORD> ./fileToTransfer.file <PUTTY_SESSION_ID>:/destination-directory/fileToTransfer.file
```

I could also run scripts using plink

```
<PUTTY_DIRECTORY>/plink.exe" <PUTTY_SESSION> -l <USERNAME> -pw <PASSWORD> -m ./myScriptToRunRemotely.sh
```

It wasn't the cleanest of solutions, but it still allows me to use it on Jenkins for deployment testing purposes.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use the [Wagon Maven plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/wagon-maven-plugin/) with its goals `upload-single` and `upload` instead of `antrun`:

> - **wagon:upload-single** uploads the specified file to a remote location.
> - **wagon:upload uploads** the specified set of files to a remote location.

Comment: This seems to require the use of settings.xml, which I would not want to use as it would require other developers to change their settings, whereas the requirement is to pass the server-url/username/password in as arguments to the maven build.

Comment: @matthewh86 I know the situation to deploy artifacts to a Tomcat instance but we automated it via a Jenkins job (depending on the build success of the artifacts' build and test jobs running prior to it), so the appropriate `settings.xml` resides on the Jenkins server. In the situation you describe devs are able to deploy artifacts to Tomcat that didn't pass integration-tests. Is this really intended?

Comment: The artifacts to be deployed are tested individually (with their own unit tests and maven build), but also need to be deployed separately to a tomcat VM so that they can be integration tested faster, rather than needing to rebuild the VM with the updated jars which can take an hour or more.

Edit: I could also be misunderstanding the use of deploy. I think it needs to work more as an optional upload target, rather than releasing and publishing the artifact itself.

Comment: I also might be misunderstanding the role of settings.xml. Is this is a global settings file, or can it be specific to this project? If it's the latter then I think I should be able to get it to work.

Comment: @matthewh86 See [Maven / Settings Reference](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html). You're not using a build/CI tool like Jenkins do you?

Comment: Yep. Will this interfere with it?

Comment: @matthewh86 It will not interfer. It will make things better. Builds and tests can be performed automatically (time triggered) and deployment to the Tomcat instance can be performed automatically, as well (depending on the test results, so that no broken code is deployed).